# How to write colon in the name of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to have have ":" in the name of one node but my compiler hanged when I put ":" there. I mean the following code in okay

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[] at (5.1,-1) {$Z_t^{1 N}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the following one doesn't work

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[] at (5.1,-1) {$Z_t^{1:N}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Colon or semicolon? I have no problem with the code, can you add a minimal example reproducing the issue?

Comment: Both colon and semicolon work fine, if the snippet is expanded to a MWE (`\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}...\end{document}`).

Comment: I don't know why it hangs whenever I run the code.

Comment: With the latest version of TeXLive, the MWE wrapper as suggested by @HeikoOberdiek works fine for me, too.

Comment: It also works for me when I put that part of my original code in a new tex file. But when I put : in my original code, that problem occurs.

Comment: Then something in your original code which you haven't shown here causes the problem. What that is we can't know. That's why you need to provide a complete example which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Try to delete temporary files created by LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, the problem was with this package \usepackage{breqn}. I removed that from my original code and this solved the issue. Thanks all.

Comment: There are [many questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=breqn+tikz) that have the topic of TikZ and `breqn`. Consensus seems to be to not use `breqn` anymore and replace it with better packages.